# Three.js repeat modes

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, webgl

As you may know, in three.js there are 3 wrapping modes

```
THREE.RepeatWrapping
THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping
THREE.MirroredRepeatWrapping
```

But in [OpenGL](http://open.gl/textures), there are 4 modes.

[Link to image](http://open.gl/media/img/c3_clamping.png)

I need the repeat mode from OpenGL called `GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER` to be available in Three.js. How do I implement a new repeat mode in three.js to provide this functionality?

**PS.** I know about consts value its 1000 - 1003 but the last one it not 1004

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240886/three-js-repeat-wrapping-texture-in-shader

Comment: @Velthune its other question, i know about `THREE.RepeatWrapping`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"CLAMP_TO_BORDER is not supported on OGL ES (WebGL)." [Source](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/public-mailing-list/archives/1002/msg00094.html).